# WCF URL Redirection using HttpModule

Tags: wcf

I want to redirect all the requests coming for Service1 to Service2.

I tried this using HTTPModule. But I have no luck. Please suggest any way to achieve this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Found this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A less code intensive way to redirecting calls can be done by the built-in [WCF RoutingService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx) capability. There is a good [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795218.aspx) that shows how to use its various features.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am looking for a solution for below problem: Client will call ServiceA (NOT SERVICEB) and in IIS I will redirect ServiceA to ServiceB.. Client still thinks it got response from ServiceA. In WCF Routing service suggested by you, Client actually calls ServiceB which is a router service... Then the router service redirect requests and the request finally sent through ServiceB endpoint. Please guide... We had 20 endpoints which is not valid now. I want those 20 endpoints of WCF1,WCF2 point to a single WCF say WCF_A. This is possible through a handler I think...

Comment: Ohhh WOW It worked like awesome :-) Thanks a lot... What I did is: I changed all SVC file html which need redirection to <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService,System.ServiceModel.Routing, version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %> then in config of the service I created filter tables... Now when request coming from say service1, service2, service3 it goes to the System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService and then using the filter table it gets redirected to different endpoint. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Rather than accepting a less than helpful answer, please post what you did as an answer and accept that, for the benefit of future readers.