# HttpModule or HttpHandler for WCF Redirecting

Tags: wcf

I want a HttpHandler or HttpModule that redirect the WCF-a Request to another WCF say WCF-b.

below code not working.

```
public class Router : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication Appl)
        {
            Appl.Context.RewritePath(@"~/WCFGateWayKid.svc");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        { }
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is 'not working'? Does it compile? Throw exceptions? Silently die? Redirect to the wrong URL?

Comment: it compiles fine. when I browse this it is redirecting me to WCFGateWayKid successfully... BUT ONLY FOR THE FIRST TIME

Comment: Again when I consume this service using a WCF Client, it is giving me this error:There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/WCFRouter/WCFGateWay.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: To diagnose the "there was no endpoint listening..." error, you may wish to use a debugging proxy like Fiddler2. Also Maybe consider using a purpose-built rewriter.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution. System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService is one of the new feature in .Net 4.0 Please refer to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313167/wcf-url-redirection-using-httpmodule/10315987#10315987) link